# Position absolute css is not working in input tag

Tags: html, css, input, position, absolute

hi the problem is that i have given position absolute to a input but i just find that absolute position is not working in input tag can anyone know?
i just wanna my layout liquid by positioning that's why i use this 
here is my Html code:

```
<div id="savevalue">
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="inpt" />
    <input type="button" value="Submit" class="btn" />
</div>
```

and here is css code:

```
.inpt{
    background:#fff;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    height:30px;
    font-size:18px;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    right:100px;
}
.btn{
    height:30px;
    background:#333;
    border:1px solid #222;
    font-size:18px;
    color:#fff;
    padding:0 15px;
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
}
```

Comment: In this what u want. see this and tell http://jsfiddle.net/3pSRS/

Comment: @Pwn that only works in Chrome

Comment: possible duplicate of [using position:absolute to set an inputs width](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1708654/using-positionabsolute-to-set-an-inputs-width)

Comment: it works same in  all browser

Comment: @Pwn what you do it only works in chrome i have tested it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

yes it works fine by using

```
width: -moz-available
```

thanks to every one